# Laravel imagecreatefromjpeg(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a certificate from an image by using laravel. When I try to use imagecreatefromjpeg() function inside HomeController its giving me error

```
imagecreatefromjpeg(/storage/DY6Gdakkwfak2B96WJsgHFNRPx6NUng1c2Iw87nG.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

My code

HomeController

```
public function show_certificate(Request $request, Certificate $certificate){
    header('content-type:image/jpeg');
    $image =  imagecreatefromjpeg(\Storage::url($certificate->certificateTemplate->template_path));
    $color=imagecolorallocate($image,19,21,22);
    $name="Vishal";
    imagettftext($image,50,0,360,360,$color,$font,$name);
    $imagejpeg($image);
    return $image;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `Storage::path()`. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-paths

Comment: It works. Thank you @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `Storage::path()`
Credits @Phil